# Javascript method won't execute because of invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript

My javascript method won't event display an `alert()` when I call the method.

I am passing a json encoded value which I encoded using `json_encode()`
The ff. value is what I get by `<?php echo json_encode($value)?>`

```
{"id":2,"title":"Announcement 1","content":"Announcement 1 Content","dateAdded":"2018-04-24 14:44:27"} {"id":1,"title":"Test Announcement Title","content":"Test Announcement Content","dateAdded":"2018-04-22 16:12:06"}
```

Then I have a javascript method which takes a `<div>` and a `json_encoded` value

```
function showEditModal(modalDivId,obj){
    alert("test");
    var modalBox = document.getElementById(modalDivId);
    var modalContentValues = document.getElementById("modalContentValues");
    modalBox.style.display = "block";
    var node = document.createElement("p");
    var text = document.createTextNode(obj); //shows [object Object]
    node.style.display = "inline";
    node.appendChild(text);
    modalContentValues.appendChild(node);
}
```

But when I apply it as onclick function, I get nothing when I click on **Edit**

```
<td>
    <a href="#" onclick="showEditModal('modalBox',<?php echo json_encode($value); ?>)">Edit</a>
</td>
```

So what I did is inspected it using **Google Chrome's inspector** to see what's going on. Then I got an error stating that there's `Invalid or Unexpected Token`

I get the error on this line after I clicked **Edit**

```
<a href="#" onclick=" showEditModal('modalBox','[{"id":2,"title":"Announcement 1","content":"Announcement 1 Content","dateAdded":"2018-04-24 14:44:27"}]'  ) " >Edit</a>
```

[image]

I hope you can help. I've been trying to figure out what's causing the error which keeps `showEditModal()` from executing for hours now. Show an `alert()` at least.

Could it be that JSON format is incorrect? or am I missing something here.

Below is another screenshot.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You have same double quotes around the event as in the JSON. You need to change/escape them: `<a href="#" onclick='showEditModal(\'modalBox\',\'[{"id":2,"title" ...`

Comment: You need to htmlencode the json before echo'ed

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks. I tried what you suggested but still can't get to correct the error.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan what do you mean by htmlencode the json? Do you mean `json_encode($value)`?

Comment: I get `<a href="#" onclick="showEditModal({"id":2,"title":"Announcement 1","content":"Announcement 1 Content","dateAdded":"2018-04-24 14:44:27"});">Edit</a>` Can you help me escape this? I can't fix it. Been trying since last night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the JSON because it contains `"` which should be encoded. You can encode it using [`htmlspecialchars`](https://secure.php.net/htmlspecialchars) or [`htmlentities`](https://secure.php.net/htmlentities).

```
<td>
  <a
    href="#"
    onclick="showEditModal('modalBox',<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($value)); ?>)"
  >Edit</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Hey! thank you very much. This has been the simplest solution so far since last night. I'm not a fan of adding nesting quotes here and there that's why I chose your answer as best answer. I'm a fan of using methods to handle strings and you solution solved my problem with very minimal code editing. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `json_encode($value)` with `json_encode($value, JSON_HEX_APOS)`.